# Why can I not run dynamic content from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I know that [Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) is a service for storing static files. But what I don't understand is, if I store some PHP files on a S3 bucket, why isn't it possible to have those files executed from a EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is a data storage service. When a file is requested from S3, it is sent to the requester, **regardless of file format**. S3 does not process the file in any way, nor does it pass content to Amazon EC2 for execution.

If you want a PHP file executed by a PHP engine, you will need to **run a web server on an Amazon EC2 instance**.

Answer (score 1):

Run directly from S3 this will never work as objects in s3 aren't presented in a way whilst stored in s3 that your local system can really use.

However good news you can pull the php down from S3 to your local system and execute it!

I use this method myself with an instance created by lambda to do some file processing. Lambda creates the instance, the bash script in the instance UserData will do an s3 copy (see below) to copy the php file down and the data file down that PHP will process and then php is called against my file.

To download a file from s3 in the cli you:

```
//save as file.php in the current directory
aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket-name/my/s3/file.php . 

//or
//save as a different filename
aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket-name/my/s3/file.php my-file.php

//or
//save it in a different folder
aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket-name/my/s3/file.php some/directory/path/file.php
```

You would then pass this file into PHP for execution like any other file.